# Handling require in a project meant to be provided as a gem

Tags: ruby, require

I'm completely lost with ruby "require" (and I don't have the option for require_relative since my code is meant to run with ruby 1.8.7.

First some sample code.

requester.rb

```
require './column/main_column'

....
```

column/main_column.rb

```
require './helper' # helper.rb being in the root dir

....
```

column/segment_column

```
require './column/main_column'
require './helper' # helper.rb being in the root dir

....
```

I'm completely lost in how should I use my requires to make my code usable inside a gem and in a standalone way (without assuming a previous gem installation). I was reading at Jekyll's code and every dependencies seems to be loaded in the main rb file which to my opinion is a bit dirty and still do resolve the problem if column/segment_column.rb needs to be called independently.

Please try to argument about different approaches and why one is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `require` files without the extension and relative to your gem project's `lib` folder.

For example, given this structure:

```
example-gem/
  lib/
    example/
      gem.rb
    example.rb
  example-gem.gemspec
```

You'd require the main `example` module using:

```
require 'example'
```

And in the `example.rb` file you'd find:

```
require 'example/gem'
```

This set of conventions is adopted by the community and is [documented on the RubyGems Guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#loading_code). If they fail, it is often because your gem's `lib` directory is not in Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH`, which usually means the gem is not installed.

Building and installing gems during development is cumbersome. For that reason, gems like [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) became part of the toolboxes of many Rubyists. Bundler lets you use your gem without having to build or install it locally. You can simply `bundle exec` a script that uses your gem or use `bundle console` in order to interact with it.